# Failure to find com.google.guava:listenablefuture:jar:sources:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava

Tags: maven, spring-security, oauth-2.0, pom.xml, openid

I'm trying to up and run openID connect certified "mitreid-connect/OpenID-Connect-Java-Spring-Server" repository.
Repo link : https://github.com/mitreid-connect/OpenID-Connect-Java-Spring-Server.git

but when run the "openid-connect-parent" POM.xml it gives error like following.

`Failure to find com.google.guava:listenablefuture:jar:sources:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced`

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
    Copyright 2018 The MIT Internet Trust Consortium

    Portions copyright 2011-2013 The MITRE Corporation

    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
    you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
    You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    limitations under the License.
 -->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.mitre</groupId>
    <artifactId>openid-connect-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MITREid Connect</name>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.oss</groupId>
        <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
        <version>9</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
            <comments>A business-friendly OSS license</comments>
        </license>
    </licenses>
    <modules>
        <module>openid-connect-common</module>
        <module>openid-connect-client</module>
        <module>openid-connect-server</module>
        <module>openid-connect-server-webapp</module>
        <module>uma-server</module>
        <module>uma-server-webapp</module>
    </modules>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:https://github.com/mitreid-connect/OpenID-Connect-Java-Spring-Server.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:mitreid-connect/OpenID-Connect-Java-Spring-Server.git</developerConnection>
        <url>https://github.com/mitreid-connect/OpenID-Connect-Java-Spring-Server.git</url>
        <tag>HEAD</tag>
    </scm>

    <developers>
        <developer>
            <id>jricher</id>
            <name>Justin Richer</name>
            <email>jricher@mit.edu</email>
        </developer>
    </developers>

    <mailingLists>
        <mailingList>
            <archive>https://mailman.mit.edu/mailman/listinfo/mitreid-connect</archive>
            <name>MITREid Connect Mailing List</name>
            <post>mitreid-connect@mit.edu</post>
        </mailingList>
    </mailingLists>

    <properties>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.7.25</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <description>A reference implementation of OpenID Connect (http://openid.net/connect/), OAuth 2.0, and UMA built on top of Java, Spring, and Spring Security. The project contains a fully functioning server, client, and utility library.</description>
    <url>https://github.com/mitreid-connect</url>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.10.4</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.7.9</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.10</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>9.4.3.v20170317</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <inherited>true</inherited>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.appfuse.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>warpath-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9</version>
                </plugin>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.appfuse.plugins
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            warpath-maven-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [3.5.0,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>add-classes</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <execute />
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wro4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
                            <artifactId>wro4j-extensions</artifactId>
                            <version>1.8.0</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <author>true</author>
                    <version>true</version>
                    <use>true</use>
                    <linksource>true</linksource>
                    <windowtitle>MITREid Connect v. ${project.version}</windowtitle>
                    <doctitle>MITREid Connect v. ${project.version}</doctitle>
                    <overview>${basedir}/src/main/javadoc/overview.html</overview>
                    <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce-maven-3</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <requireMavenVersion>
                                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                                </requireMavenVersion>
                            </rules>
                            <fail>true</fail>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <reportPlugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                            <configuration>
                                <dependencyDetailsEnabled>false</dependencyDetailsEnabled>
                                <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
                            </configuration>
                            <reports>
                                <report>index</report>
                                <report>cim</report>
                                <report>dependencies</report>
                                <report>dependency-convergence</report>
<!--                                <report>dependency-info</report> -->
                                <report>dependency-management</report>
                                <report>help</report>
                                <report>issue-tracking</report>
                                <report>license</report>
                                <report>mailing-list</report>
                                <report>modules</report>
                                <report>plugin-management</report>
                                <report>plugins</report>
                                <report>project-team</report>
                                <report>scm</report>
                                <report>summary</report>
                            </reports>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                            <configuration>
                                <author>true</author>
                                <version>true</version>
                                <use>true</use>
                                <linksource>true</linksource>
                                <windowtitle>MITREid Connect ${project.name} v. ${project.version}</windowtitle>
                                <doctitle>MITREid Connect ${project.name} v. ${project.version}</doctitle>
                                <overview>${basedir}/src/main/javadoc/overview.html</overview>
                                <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                            <configuration>
                                <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                            <configuration>
                                <junitArtifactName>junit:junit</junitArtifactName>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>**/*_Roo_*</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        </plugin>
                    </reportPlugins>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <issueManagement>
        <url>https://github.com/mitreid-connect/OpenID-Connect-Java-Spring-Server/issues</url>
        <system>GitHub Issues</system>
    </issueManagement>
    <ciManagement>
        <system>Travis CI</system>
        <url>https://travis-ci.org/mitreid-connect/OpenID-Connect-Java-Spring-Server</url>
    </ciManagement>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>listenablefuture</artifactId>
            </dependency>


            <!-- Spring -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.22.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Jackson -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.8</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.8</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Spring Security -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-bom</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.11.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Servlet -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Database -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.42</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
                <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <version>42.0.0.jre7</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
                <version>11.1.0.7.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
                <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.1</version>
            </dependency>


            <!-- Logging -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.17</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Test -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.12</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
                <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
                <version>3.4</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.5</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- MITREid Connect components -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mitre</groupId>
                <artifactId>openid-connect-common</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mitre</groupId>
                <artifactId>openid-connect-client</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mitre</groupId>
                <artifactId>openid-connect-server</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mitre</groupId>
                <artifactId>openid-connect-server-webapp</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>war</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mitre</groupId>
                <artifactId>openid-connect-server-webapp</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>warpath</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mitre</groupId>
                <artifactId>uma-server</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mitre</groupId>
                <artifactId>uma-server-webapp</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>war</type>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Other libraries -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                <version>27.0-jre</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
                <version>4.5.3</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
                <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
                <version>5.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
                <version>[1.52,)</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.core</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>wro4j-extensions</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
            <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Then i added the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>listenablefuture</artifactId>
    <version>9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava</version>
</dependency>
```

But the issue is remaining as same.

Do anyone have a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 4):

Adding this worked for me

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>listenablefuture</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```